# Consecutive urllib2 POST gives 404

Tags: python, http, cookies, urllib2

The problem that I have — and try to solve with Python — is to make consecutive POST requests (completing an online form) for a website (specifically, a free online demo of an API at http://demo.travelportuniversalapi.com). I am not able to acquire the results page so far — been at this for two days now.

The code I employ is:

```
import sys
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

class website:
    def __init__(self):
        self.host = 'demo.travelportuniversalapi.com'
        self.ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0'  
        self.session = cookielib.CookieJar() #session devine o instanta a obiectului cookielib
        pass     

    def get(self):
        try:
            url = 'http://demo.travelportuniversalapi.com/(S(cexfuhghvlzyzx5n0ysesra1))/Search' #this varies every 20 minutes
            data = None
            headers = {'User-Agent': self.ua}
            request = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
            self.session.add_cookie_header(request)
            response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
            self.session.extract_cookies(response, request)
            url = response.geturl()


            data = {'From': 'lhr', 'To': 'ams', 'Departure' : '9/4/2013','Return' : '9/6/2013'}
            headers = {'User-Agent': self.ua, "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                       }            
            request = urllib2.Request(url, urllib.urlencode(data), headers, 20)
            self.session.add_cookie_header(request)
            response = urllib2.urlopen(request, timeout=30) #HTTP Error 404: Not Found - aici am eroare
            self.session.extract_cookies(response, request)                
        except urllib2.URLError as e:
            print >> sys.stderr, e
            return None

rt = website()
rt.get()
```

The error that I receive at the last `urllib2.Request` is HTTP Error 404: Not Found. I am not sure my cookies are working.

Monitoring HTTP packets with an addon in the browser I noticed the following header when the POST is sent in a broswer: 'X-Requested-With   XMLHttpRequest' — is this relevant?

Comment: Don't abuse demo APIs.

Comment: I want to do some statistics testing, since i believe the real API seems to give different results from this demo API.